# php , include, inject code of de header in the base file

Tags: php

The body of the base file has a include ' slider.php '.
In de slider.php there are css and javascript files that need to be load.

Because of the include it will but all of that in the body where the include is posted.

My question is: Is it possible if you have a include the file. You can say in the include put  css and javascript  in the `<header>` tag and not where the include is made.

```
[index.php]
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<div id="slider">
<?php require_once( INCLUDES . 'slider.php');?>
</div>

    </body>
</html>



[slider.php]
<?php
<!-- slider -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/normalize.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/demo.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/component.css" />
<script src="/slider.min.js"></script>
<script src="scattered_slider/classie.js"></script>


<div class="row header">
etc...
```

Comment: Can you show us the contents of your files (relevant for this question)?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible to do that using only a single include/require.

The fastest solution would be to use two different files "slider_header.php" containing the javascript/css tags and "slider_body.php" containing the actual slider html.

Then you could include them like this:

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <?php require( INCLUDES . 'slider_header.php');?>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="slider">
        <?php require( INCLUDES . 'slider_body.php');?>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Maybe you should consider using a proper template engine like [Twig](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/), but this requires a little bit more effort to set it up in the first place.